# Is it a conflict of interest if an examiner of a graduate thesis is a coauthor of a paper with the supervisor of the thesis?

Tags: conflict-of-interest, thesis-committee

Is it a conflict of interest if an examiner of a graduate thesis is a coauthor of a paper/papers with the supervisor of the thesis? Do you think that this would sway a positive or negative result or bias?

Comment: @cheersmate but not everyone publishes during their PhD -- in fact, I believe in the humanities it's much more common to turn thesis chapters into papers after the PhD is complete.

Comment: A conflict for whom, exactly? The examiner? The student?

Answer (score 3):

No, it can be unavoidable.

You haven't named a country, but in the US in the sciences, it's fairly normal to have 3-4 people from your department and one from another department in the same university. If  your department isn't that large, those 3-4 probably have collaborated with the supervisor, and the external member may have been brought in because they *are* a collaborator.

Plus, you don't usually defend until you are ready. So examiners aren't often put it in the place of needing to decline to endorse a dissertation.

That said, I would still say it's best practice to avoid it as best you can.

Comment: I think this a good answer for the US. It may not hold universally where, in some countries, a defense is sometimes a bit adversarial.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be a conflict of interest. As Azor Ahai said, you haven't specified which country or field you are referring to. In my experience (in the UK, in physics), people who have written a paper with your supervisor are usually prohibited from being either your external or internal examiner, and the same goes for anyone you yourself have written a paper with.

While it's nice to believe that someone with a close working relationship with a student or that student's supervisor could assess the student's thesis fairly, unconscious bias is always at play (which can work both positively and negatively). To avoid any such problems, choose examiners with which you and your supervisor have as few personal and professional ties as possible.

Comment: I'd note that the restrictions are often time limited: at my UK university it's co-authorships in the past 5 years that are the bar.

Comment: At my University (Canada), the *external* examiner is required to be "arms' length" (no co-authorship, participation in grants, etc.). No rules about internal examiners.

Answer (score 2):

I am on quite friendly terms with 80% of the faculty members in my department. Does that mean I have a conflict of interest if I sit on a dissertation committee for one of their students? Will my favorable view of the advisor sway my judgment positively? What about the other 20% I’m not on friendly terms with (probably with some reason...)? Should people worry that my judgment will be swayed *negatively* if I sit on a committee for one of *their* students? If so, when would I ever be allowed to be on anyone’s dissertation committee?

I know that’s not the situation you’re describing exactly, but the point is that, if you interpret “conflict of interest” in some idealized, completely literal sense, then everyone in academia has a conflict of interest about 90% of the duties they perform. Essentially, to be human is to be in a state of perpetual conflict about much of what you do professionally. This is ridiculous, and such an interpretation of what it means to have a conflict renders the whole notion of a conflict of interest completely useless.

Basically you’re overthinking this. Professors are professionals, and are trusted to perform their duties ethically and impartially. There might be isolated cases of professors failing their colleague’s graduate student because of some vendetta or feud, but that’s beside the point. There are isolated cases of *every sort of bad thing* happening somewhere, to someone. The particular concern you are raising is at a level that’s so hypothetical that no sensible person will spend any amount of time worrying about it. So no, in a practical, realistic sense, it is not a conflict of interest.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. In our system there are two referees of a PhD thesis (one for a master's thesis) and they should not be coauthors unless it is a paper with many authors and there was no close cooperation between those two. Otherwise it could indeed be considered to be a conflict of interest.

(And I did not even mean large cooperations like ATLAS or CMS in high energy physics where everyone around probably is a member of the same collaboration and hence automatically a coauthor. I mean papers where they do have some actual connection to the specific paper.)

The actual examination - or defense actually, the state exam(rigorosum or viva) happens earlier, even years earlier - however, is done by a stable comittee of say 8-10 members (plus the referees) and it is very common that some of the comittee members happen to be coauthors.